# Wireless keyboard intermittently working on m1 usb hub

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb, apple-silicon

I have a M1 Macbook air and a Logitech MK520 wireless keyboard that I connect to the laptop via a Logitech unifying receiver connected to a USB Type C hub.

The keyboard works most of the time, but on occasion pressing the keys doesn't get detected. The USB hub frequently overheats, but I'm not sure if that's the reason. I tried using several USB hubs and had the same issue, also tried using a new unifying receiver.

The keyboard and receiver work without issues on Windows laptops.

How can I figure out the cause of this issue? Thanks

Comment: Does the keyboard start flaking out when the hub is hot?  Can you test the keyboard directly connected to the Macbook instead of through the hub for some length of time that doesn't impinge on your productivity?  Helpful aside: I needed to test several USBC hubs for my institution and I found that not all of them are created equal. Those manufactured by Anker or Kramer are built to a higher standard than the others I tested. _Note: no financial or other ties to Anker or Kramer --  just a satisfied customer._

Comment: I can't connect the keyboard directly as it has a USB type A connector, so it has to go through the hub. I'll check to see if the issue always occurs while the hub is over heating